# Dynamically changing cell type on a table

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have tried to google for hints on this problem but haven't found anyone suitable.
I'm in a scenario where I need to change the type of cells in a table based on whether the user has authenticated or not. Specifically: the user executes the app and the landing page is the table. In it, each cell (of type, say, STANDARD_CELL) subscribes to a (very frequently changing) source of information and starts getting data. In order to login, then, the user leaves the screen with the table and lands on another screen where he/she can provide credentials. Upon authentication, the user should be able to go back to the previous table and this should now have a different type (say, TRADE_CELL).
My trouble is that this does not seem to happen and cell type stays the same as the first load.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you post some code of your tableview delegate and datasource so we can try and see where the problem is, for example your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath:' method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're checking the status of your authentication in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in order to serve up the right type and that when transitioning to authenticated or unauthenticated you call `reloadData` on your tableview.